# Unexpected error when reading from a text file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read text from a file (should be pretty easy right?). As far as I recall, the syntax should look something like

```
FILE *filename;
filename = fopen("filename.txt", "r"); /*when file is the same 
                                        folder of the .exe*/
```

Below is my code. When I run it, I simply get "Error", which is the prompt I wanted in case of an error. I included here a global struct declaration because it's literally the only other thing in the code, even though I'm positive it's not causing any problem with opening the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list {
    char subject[20];
    char prof_name[20];
    char prof_surname[20];
    char period[20];
    int credits;
    int pass_rate;
};

int main()
{
    struct list data[80];

    FILE *prof;

    prof = fopen("professor.txt", "r");

    if (prof == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
return 0;
}
```

The file has the correct name and extension, it's in the same folder as the .exe (I've also tried with the address, it still does the same). I feel like I'm going to get crazy if I look at the code even for just one more minute. There must be something I missed

Comment: I am 100% sure the file is not in the same folder with the working directory.

Comment: Write your code to get a more useful error message: `if (prof == NULL) {perror("professor.txt");...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the comment "when file is the same folder of the .exe", that is incorrect.

Instead relative paths (like your `professor.txt`) is relative from the process current working directory. Which might be very different from the location of the `.exe` file.

My *guess* is that you're running inside Visual Studio (or other IDE) which places the executable files in a sub-directory. The working directory when running, though, is usually the project root directory.

So either go into the project settings and change the working directory when running the program into the directory where the file is located, or move the file to the actual working directory.

---

You can use the [`_getcwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd?view=vs-2017) function to get the process working directory, to verify that it is what you believe it is.

Comment: Thank you man, _getcwd saved my life. For whatever reason the working directory changed, I would have never guessed it.